# Extend missing data in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, missing-data, gaps-and-islands

I have following set od data:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17.01.2023 | Bad |
| 1 | 17.01.2023 | Good |
| 1 | 18.01.2023 | Enough |
| 1 | 17.01.2023 | Good |
| 1 | 15.03.2023 | Bad |
| 1 | 20.03.2023 | Good |
| 2 | 10.01.2023 | Bad |
| 2 | 19.01.2023 | Enough |
| 2 | 25.02.2023 | Bad |
| 2 | 11.03.2023 | Bad |
| 3 | 20.12.2022 | Good |
| 3 | 13.03.2023 | Good |
| 3 | 29.03.2023 | Enough |

The goal is to have an SQL report (to download it to excel and create an chart) without missing data in each month. For example, for the id=1 we have data for January and March (February is missing). In this case we should take the value from the previous existing month. If within the month we have more values then we take the last one. So the expected result is:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18.01.2023 | Enough |
| **1** | **28.02.2023** | **Enough** |
| 1 | 20.03.2023 | Good |
| 2 | 19.01.2023 | Enough |
| 2 | 25.02.2023 | Bad |
| 2 | 11.03.2023 | Bad |
| 3 | 20.12.2022 | Good |
| **3** | **31.01.2023** | **Good** |
| **3** | **28.02.2023** | **Good** |
| 3 | 29.03.2023 | Enough |

We can use the EOMONTH() to have the end of month. Important is that we'll have one (the latest) value for each month to have continuity of data in the chart.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

In the database we have also a table with the months. I've tried to as following:

```
SELECT
m.month
,t2.ID
,t2.value
FROM months
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
t.ID AS ID
,MONTH(t.Date) AS month
,t.value AS value
FROM table AS t
) AS t2 ON t2.month = m.month
```

But it works as an INNER JOIN and I don't have even NULL for the missing moths.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply sample data, DDL and DML are the best way. Otherwise please use Markdown tables. Images do not help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that i like to use:

```sql
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  id,CONVERT(date, date, 104) AS date, value
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1, N'17.01.2023', N'Bad')
        ,   (1, N'17.01.2023', N'Good')
        ,   (1, N'18.01.2023', N'Enough')
        ,   (1, N'17.01.2023', N'Good')
        ,   (1, N'15.03.2023', N'Bad')
        ,   (1, N'20.03.2023', N'Good')
        ,   (2, N'10.01.2023', N'Bad')
        ,   (2, N'19.01.2023', N'Enough')
        ,   (2, N'25.02.2023', N'Bad')
        ,   (2, N'11.03.2023', N'Bad')
        ,   (3, N'20.12.2022', N'Good')
        ,   (3, N'13.03.2023', N'Good')
        ,   (3, N'29.03.2023', N'Enough')
    ) t (ID,Date,Value)
    )
,cte2 AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   LAG(date) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS prevdate
    ,   LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS prevValue
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, EOMONTH(date) ORDER BY date DESC) AS sort
    FROM    cte
)
SELECT  id, date, value
FROM    cte2
WHERE   sort = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  id, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - x.counter, date)), prevValue
FROM    cte2 c
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  TOP 40 row_number() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid) AS counter
        FROM    sys.objects so
        CROSS APPLY sys.columns sc
    ) x
WHERE   x.counter < DATEDIFF(month, c.prevdate, c.date)
ORDER BY id, date
```

I create a union of "proper" rows (ie. last date per month/year/id) together with generated rows.

For generated rows, what i do is compare previous month value to current date, and if it's more than 1, then i duplicate the rows by using a fake series table (you can use GENERATE_SERIES or whatever else method you have available), every duplicate row will have date that is x months back. Finally i apply EOMONTH on the date, to get the correct date.

Comment: Hi,
your solution is fine but doesn't work if we have following data:
         (4, N'29.03.2022', N'Enough')
We don't have filled data till the March 2023

Comment: It didn't really say you have to backfill if data is completely missing

Comment: how far back is one supposed to go? Start of the year? 1970?

Comment: Since the earliest date in the set of data- so in the new version set of data: 29.03.2022

Answer (score 0):

One option may use the following steps:

- extract the last [Date], [Value] for each of your ids
- generate a combination of your ids with a partial calendar table
- left join the calendar table with your lastvalues table on matching ids and month dates
- address the remaining gaps and islands problem by rebuilding the partitions (one non-null value + following null values to be assigned to the non-null one)

Each of these operations is done in a different subquery, structured as follows here:

```
WITH lastvalues AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
                    FIRST_VALUE([Date])  OVER(PARTITION BY [ID], MONTH([Date]) 
                                              ORDER     BY [Date] DESC       ) AS [Date],
                    FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID], MONTH([Date]) 
                                              ORDER     BY [Date] DESC       ) AS [Value],
                    MONTH([Date]) AS monthdate
    FROM tab 
), dates AS (
    SELECT ids.ID,
           EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, value, '2022-12-01')) AS [Date],
           MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, value, '2022-12-01')) AS monthdate
    FROM       GENERATE_SERIES(0, 3)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tab) ids
), alldates AS (
    SELECT dates.ID, 
           COALESCE(cte.[Date], dates.[Date]) AS [Date],
           cte.[Value],
           COUNT([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY dates.ID ORDER BY dates.[Date]) AS parts
    FROM      dates
    LEFT JOIN lastvalues cte
           ON dates.monthdate = cte.monthdate AND dates.id = cte.id
)
SELECT ID, 
       [Date],
       MAX([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, parts) AS [Value]
FROM alldates
```

**Output**:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-31 | null |
| 1 | 2023-01-18 | Enough |
| 1 | 2023-02-28 | Enough |
| 1 | 2023-03-20 | Good |
| 2 | 2022-12-31 | null |
| 2 | 2023-01-19 | Enough |
| 2 | 2023-02-25 | Bad |
| 2 | 2023-03-11 | Bad |
| 3 | 2022-12-20 | Good |
| 3 | 2023-01-31 | Good |
| 3 | 2023-02-28 | Good |
| 3 | 2023-03-29 | Enough |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HlLOogUy).